# How do make a child div to not redirect on the parent a tag href?

Tags: html

Is it possible to make the div with the `not_linked` id to not redirect the browser to the parent href?  There is a good reason I am doing this but I've removed the long code for it and have condensed it here to this basic example:

```
<a href='google.com'>
  <div>Part 1</div>
  <div id='not_linked'>Middle</div>
  <div>Part 3</div>
</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery(function() { jQuery('#not_linked').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });});
see: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: **Don't do it!** There is no such thing as a good reason for doing what you're doing. Instead take the `#not_linked` div out of the `<a>` element, and position it over the `<a>`.

Comment: Tamil you answered the question.  Can you post it as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

you can probably do it with a bit of javascript, to analyze the actual click target and see which text was actually clicked. If it was Middle, then abort the link. But why go that trouble when you can simply do

```
<a href="http://google.com"><div>Part 1</div></a>
<div>Middle</div>
<a href="http://google.com"><div>Part 3</div></a>
```

Also note that this is invalid html. `div` is a block-level element and should NOT be placed inside in-line elements (the `<a>`).